# how to search with star (*) in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to search with *.
I have

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="500" Height="20" ID="tbInfo"></asp:TextBox>
```

search method: when I search without star* is normal search, but when I set a star* LINQ query like `tbInfo.Contains()`

Example:

```
I set in textbox: Michael - 1 result, 
I set in textbox: Michael* - 20 results
```

I hope someone understand me. 10x

Comment: Please share the actual C# code. It's not clear what you are doing from the question at the moment.

Comment: you want to get result from list ?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do some coding yourself.

A sample query:

```
var q = (from c in db.Customers
         where c.CompanyName.Contains(name)
         select c)
        .ToList();
```

> The above example will always search anywhere in CompanyName for a
>   match. But you need to give your users a little more control over the
>   match method by allowing them to supply wild-card characters at either
>   the start or end of the text to match. This means you are left to
>   dynamically build your query based on the presence and location of the
>   wild-card characters.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

    public static class LinqExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereLike<TSource>(
            this IQueryable<TSource> source,
            Expression<Func<TSource, string>> valueSelector,
            string value,
            char wildcard)
        {
            return source.Where(BuildLikeExpression(valueSelector, value, wildcard));
        }

        public static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildLikeExpression<TElement>(
            Expression<Func<TElement, string>> valueSelector,
            string value,
            char wildcard)
        {
            if (valueSelector == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");

            var method = GetLikeMethod(value, wildcard);

            value = value.Trim(wildcard);
            var body = Expression.Call(valueSelector.Body, method, Expression.Constant(value));

            var parameter = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, parameter);
        }

        private static MethodInfo GetLikeMethod(string value, char wildcard)
        {
            var methodName = "Contains";

            var textLength = value.Length;
            value = value.TrimEnd(wildcard);
            if (textLength > value.Length)
            {
                methodName = "StartsWith";
                textLength = value.Length;
            }

            value = value.TrimStart(wildcard);
            if (textLength > value.Length)
            {
                methodName = (methodName == "StartsWith") ? "Contains" : "EndsWith";
                textLength = value.Length;
            }

            var stringType = typeof(string);
            return stringType.GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { stringType });
        }
    }
```

> Usage of the WhereLike extension method is as follows:

```
var searchTerm = "*Inc";
var q = db.Customers
        .WhereLike(c => c.CompanyName, searchTerm, '*')
        .ToList();
```

source of this is found [here](http://trentacular.com/2010/08/linq-to-entities-wild-card-like-extension-method/).

Comment: please don't post "link-only" answers!

Comment: Add some more info, so that it may survive link rot.

Comment: I hope you have asked the blogs author to copy&paste his work here ... anyway yes this is better

Comment: I've added the source, I've used quotes, and I am not claiming it is my work, so I see no problem with it.